# Upgraded to Rails 5.2.0, but no storage.yml created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I followed [this tutorial](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/rails-5-2-active-storage-and-beyond) on upgrading an existing app to rails 5.2.0.  After including rails 5.2.0 in my gem-file, and installing it locally, and after bundle update and bundle install and running

```
rails active_storage:install
```

then `rake db:migrate`

I do not see the storage.yml file in my app.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the authors of the above tutorial responded to my email on this topic, he said the storage.yml is not generated in an existing app.  He suggests creating the file by hand and pasting in code from the Active Storage docs, or try generating a new app in a temp folder and cut/paste the storage.yml file.